# Which is faster? ORDER BY Timestamp or WHERE Timestamp =

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I'm setting up a sqlite database that will monitor a number of physical sensors. A separate application is saving data for several months... This application will just monitor that data acquisition. I want to make sure my query is as efficient as possible.

I would like to pull the last few readings from the sensors. There will be about 20 different types of sensors, each with a different sensor ID.

This is just for monitoring purposes, so it doesn't have to precisely capture all the data, just display recent values.

Which of these would be faster? why?

```
sqlCommString = "SELECT * FROM Samples WHERE Timestamp = '" + DateTime10SecondsAgo + "'

sqlCommString = "SELECT * FROM Samples ORDER BY Timestamp DESC LIMIT 20"
```

Comment: Don't you want `Timestamp >= ...`?  Also, why don't you try both and find out which is faster?

Comment: I did Timestamp equals, because the sensors read every second, so I'd collect a full set of readings always ten seconds behind, rather than in between readings. but yeah, might as well just do >=. Thanks. Will test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's *likely* that the first one (although it should be `>=` rather than `=` to get the last few samples) would be faster.

The second has to retrieve *all* the rows and then sort them (though an index would make the sort unnecessary, and you very much *should* index that column for this use case) and then throw some away.

The first only retrieves those which are needed.

In general, it's more efficient to reduce the size of your data set as quickly as possible (have a look into cardinality one day, it's a fascinating concept if you're into that sort of thing).

But, as with all optimisations, *measure, don't guess!* Especially with databases where the query itself is only *one* part of the performance equation - the makeup of the data also can have a significant impact.